# Error : End of script output before headers while submiting html form in python-cgi

Tags: html, python-3.x, xampp, cgi, form-submit

I am trying to create a form and getting the data entered by user into my script using python-cgi but I am getting this error message "**End of script output before headers: processname.cgi".** I have followed various blogs and tutorials but couldn't make it work.

Here is my form and cgi script. I am using python3 and xampp server on my local machine(MAC OSX)

form.html

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Get name from User</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="processname.cgi">
      Please Enter Your name: <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="e.g. John" autofocus
  required="required"/>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submitname" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my cgi-script: processname.cgi

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
def htmlTop():
  print('''Content-type:text/html\n\n
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>My Server Side template</title>
  </head>
  <body>''')
def htmlTail():
  print('''</body>
  </html>''')
def getData():
  formData = cgi.FieldStorage()
  firstname = formData.getvalue("username")
  return firstname
if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    htmlTop()
    firstname = getData()
    print("Hello {0}".format(firstname))
    htmlTail()
   except:
    cgi.print_exception()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.You have to make your script executable and then restart the server.

```
chmod 705 .../folders/scriptname.cgi
```

will make the script executable.

Comment: Restarting the server is not related at all.